# Spring Boot OAuth2 SSO not working when authorizeRequests antMatcher is not set to root url

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security, single-sign-on, spring-security-oauth2

I've been trying to make an application with Spring Boot that uses Google as an identity provider for logging in.
The following configuration (using Spring Security) seems to work for this:

```
@Configuration
@EnableOAuth2Sso
public class SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.
                antMatcher("/**")
                    .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/", "/login**","/callback/", "/error**")
                    .permitAll()
                .anyRequest()
                    .authenticated();
    }
}
```

However, I only really want to secure a small part of the website (e.g. everything under the /secured/ path).
So I thought changing the antMatcher that requests are authorized for would work for this:

```
...
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.
            antMatcher("/secured**")
                .authorizeRequests()
...
```

When I try this the application still redirects me to /login, but it gives me a 404 on that page instead of redirecting me to google's servers.

I could of course add all public urls to the permitAll antMatcher, but that seems cumbersome to do everytime a new one is added.
Putting all public things on a /public** path is also not something I'd like to do since it'd look weird in the url

Could anybody shed some light on what is happening here or maybe offer alternative solutions?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Your code looks fine but CSRF Configuration is found missing, might that be the problem?

Comment: @PranjalGore Did you mean disabling csrf by configuration? That does not seem to make a difference unfortunately :/